# Install Android Studio on another PC by copying the folder

Tags: android-studio

I have installed Android Studio and downloaded everything that it needs. I've changed the editor's colors, the shortcuts, etc.

Now I want to copy it to my laptop and to another PC, I found Android Studio at  `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio` but will it work if I simply copy this folder into other systems ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. But you can export old settings using `File` `Export Settings` and import it back using `File` `Import Settings`. You can choose what you want to export/import.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy Android SDK and Java JDK as well.